# Android: Dynamic navigation bar, how to?

Tags: android, user-interface, navigationbar

I have serached for patterns like 'dynamic navigation bar' or 'build action tabs context specific' but i can manage to find any good example of how could be done a navigation bar (like the one in windows explorer since vista: [example](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-is/windows-8/files-folders-windows-explorer) -> 4. Address bar )

I have a bunch of data ordered by category in a tree structure and i would very much like the user to be able to navigate back to any node (main page, category or subcategory) he previously selected with one touch.

I've never seen any app actually use this on android so i wonder if it is even possible.

Is there something similar to what im searching for? if not do you know where i could get started?

Comment: Like in "ES Explorer ?"
If you exactly know where you are each time, you can simply put in a stack every folder the user touch. Then ,when you want to display the bar, just take the last element of the stack. Each time you want to go to the parent folder, delete the first element of the stack

Comment: okay i figured that i would have to do something based on a stack. Which activity/fragment tabs object is the best atm? i understand some are deprecated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just to close the case: i used stacks and made it from scratch. I was wondering if there was any built-in component.